# Why two lowest and highest priority threads still interleave?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider having the following class:

```
public class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
       private Thread t;
       private String threadName;

       RunnableDemo( String name) {
          threadName = name;
          System.out.println("Creating thread " +  threadName );
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
          System.out.println("Running thread" +  threadName );
          try {
             for(int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + ", iteration: " + i);
                // Let the thread sleep for a while.
                Thread.sleep(50);
             }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " interrupted.");
          }
          System.out.println(threadName + " exiting.");
       }

       public void Fire (int priority) {
          System.out.println("Starting thread " +  threadName );
          if (t == null) {
             t = new Thread (this, threadName);
             t.setPriority(priority);
             t.start ();
          }
       }
}
```

And another class to test it:

```
public class TestThread {

    public TestThread() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          RunnableDemo R1 = new RunnableDemo( "RunnableDemo-One");      
          RunnableDemo R2 = new RunnableDemo( "RunnableDemo-Two");

          R1.Fire(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
          R2.Fire(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    }

}
```

The output of this code snippet when run is:

```
Creating thread RunnableDemo-One
Creating thread RunnableDemo-Two
Starting thread RunnableDemo-One
Starting thread RunnableDemo-Two
Running threadRunnableDemo-One
Thread RunnableDemo-One, iteration: 4
Running threadRunnableDemo-Two
Thread RunnableDemo-Two, iteration: 4
Thread RunnableDemo-Two, iteration: 3
Thread RunnableDemo-One, iteration: 3
Thread RunnableDemo-Two, iteration: 2
Thread RunnableDemo-One, iteration: 2
Thread RunnableDemo-Two, iteration: 1
Thread RunnableDemo-One, iteration: 1
RunnableDemo-Two exiting.
RunnableDemo-One exiting.
```

In other words, despite one thread having MAX_PRIORITY and the other having MIN_PRIORITY, the system still interleaves between them as if they were of equal priority. **Why is that**?

Phrasing the same question differently: Is there a scenario or code modification in which the output of the program would be:

```
Thread RunnableDemo-One, iteration: 4
Thread RunnableDemo-One, iteration: 3
Thread RunnableDemo-One, iteration: 2
Thread RunnableDemo-One, iteration: 1

Thread RunnableDemo-Two, iteration: 4
Thread RunnableDemo-Two, iteration: 3
Thread RunnableDemo-Two, iteration: 2
Thread RunnableDemo-Two, iteration: 1
```

That is, while still keeping them as separate and independent threads?

Comment: Why would thread two hang around without doing any work while thread one is *sleeping*? Would you expect it to never get any work done if the high priority thread decided to sleep for multiple days? Priority is for about allocating CPU time... when a thread is sleeping, it's not using CPU time.

Comment: Can your CPU run two threads in parallel ?

Comment: you need to brush up your multi programming basics before asking such a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM presents the threads to OS and here the priority plays a role again based on JVM scheduling algorithm but its the OS which finally decides and thus, it's own algorithm would try to use as much as possible from CPU core cycles among the multiple threads which are contesting for resource.
 
 However, if there is a use case in which you want to have one thread completing before second, you can consider using join().

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, when I removed the sleep() completely I evidenced the system gravitating towards the higher priority thread, albeit not totally.

Comment: Beyond the argument given by the answer: keep in mind that such priorities might only kick in when your system is under high load. While there is "enough CPU" for everybody you might not see any effects of prioritizing threads against each other (if at all: I lately tried to have threads with different priorities increase different counters; and no matter what I did, they were always increasing the counters at the same pace).